# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') ReactJs Getting data from a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

im tring to fetch data from a file called dummyData.js
It has the following structure.

```
 export const Posts = [
    {
      id: 1,
      desc: "Love For All, Hatred For None.",
      photo: "assets/post/1.jpeg",
      date: "5 mins ago",
      userId: 1,
      like: 32,
      comment: 9,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      photo: "assets/post/2.jpeg",
      date: "15 mins ago",
      userId: 2,
      like: 2,
      comment: 1,
    },
```

Now i am mapping the data from that file.

```
export default function Feed() {
    return (
        <div className="feed">
            <div className="feedWrapper">
               <Share/>
               {Posts.map((p) => (
                   <Post key={p.id} post={p}/>
               ))}
         
            </div>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

here is my post component

```
export default function Post({post}) {
  console.log(post);
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="post">
                <div className="postWrapper">
                    <div className="postTop">
                        <div className="topLeft">
                            <img className="profilePic" src="/files/prof.png" alt="" />
                            <span className="postUsername">Kasun Gayantha</span>
                            <span className="postDate"> 5 mins ago</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="topRight">
                            <MoreVert/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="postCenter">
                        <span className="postText">hey this is first post</span>
                        <img src="/files/prof.png" alt="" className="postImage" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="postBottom">
                        <div className="postBottomLeft">
                            <ThumbUpAltIcon htmlColor="blue" className="likeIcon"/>
                            <FavoriteIcon htmlColor="red" className="likeIcon"/>
                            <span className="postLikeCounter">32 people like it </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="postBottomRight">
                            <span className="postCommentText"> comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have components called feed.jsx,Post.jsx

but when I compile this the following error comes up

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

 return (
   9 |     <div className="feed">
  10 |         <div className="feedWrapper">
> 11 |            <Share/>
^  12 |            {Posts.map((p) => (
  13 |                <Post key={p.id} post={p}/>
  14 |            ))}
```

error is in from the line no 11.
Im new to react , struggling to fix this. I have looked at many solutions on the internet.

Comment: How to import `Posts `?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because the `Posts` array is `undefined`.

Do `(Posts || []).map(.....)` so that the `.map` is not called on an `undefined` variable.

You can do something like:

```js
return (
    <div className="feed">
        <div className="feedWrapper">
            <Share />
            {(Posts || []).map(p => (
                <Post key={p.id} post={p} />
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check for the length before looping through

```js
export default function Feed() {
    return (
        <div className="feed">
            <div className="feedWrapper">
               <Share/>
               { Posts && Posts.length ?
                Posts.map((p) => (
                   <Post key={p.id} post={p}/>
               )) : null}
         
            </div>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up when you’re trying to use `.map` on an array, but that array isn’t defined yet.

You could try these options

1. Defining `Posts` as an empty array inside the state.
2. You could condionally render `Post` component based on its length

   ```
   return (
       <div className="feed">
           <div className="feedWrapper">
              <Share/>
              {Posts.length &&
                   Posts.map((p) => (
                      <Post key={p.id} post={p}/>
                   ))
               }     
           </div>
       </div>
    )
   ```